# Render fetched API json object in react component Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

i have my json received from api call and is saved in the state "data"

i want to show a loading screen while api is being fetched like i have a state for that too  "Loading"

Loading ? Then render data on elements : Loading..

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    Fetchapi();
  }, []);

  const Fetchapi = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get("http://localhost:8081/api").then((response) => {
        const allData = response.data;
        setData(allData);
      });
      setLoading(true);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
             i need my json object rendered here i tried map method on data and i am 
             getting errors and i have my json2ts interfaces imported in this 

    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
interface ResponseData {
  id: string
  // other data ...
}
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<ResponseData | null>(null)
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    Fetchapi()
  }, [])

  const Fetchapi = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true) // USE BEFORE FETCH
      await axios.get("http://localhost:8081/api").then(response => {
        setLoading(false) // SET LOADING FALSE AFTER GETTING DATA
        const allData: ResponseData = response.data
        setData(allData)
      })
    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false) // ALSO SET LOADING FALSE IF ERROR
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  if (Loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
  if (data?.length)
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map(d => (
          <div key={d.id}>{d.id}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  return <div>no data found</div>
}
export default App
```

Comment: Well the loading part is all clear also i am getting error "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'" I have too much confusion on this part did i need interfaces and if yes how can i use interface to eliminate this

Comment: also a new error where app component is being imported and rendered "App' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Element | Element[]' is not a valid JSX element."

Comment: well i eliminated the first error by "data.map((d:RootObject) => <div key={d.bestTrophies}>{d.donations}</div>"  where RootObject is the interface

Comment: you need to define type for response object, update my ans with typescript

Answer (score 1):

I would camelCase your values/functions and move your `fetchApi` into the effect itself, as currently its a dependency.

Put `setLoading(true)` above your fetch request as currently it's not activating until the fetch goes through.

Then below it put `setLoading(false)`, and also inside of your catch.

In your return statement you can now add something like this:

```js
<div>
   {loading ? "Loading..." : JSON.stringify(data)}
</div>
```

**Edit**

Example for the commented requests.

```js
import { Clan } from "../clan.jsx"

// App
<div>
   {loading ? "Loading..." : <Clan data={data}/>}
</div>

// New file clan.jsx
export const Clan = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
         <h1>{props.data.clan.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: yep that worked for the loading part and you using JSON.stringify on data  but suppose i have data.troops.level how can i access this in typescript and suppose render that in h1 tag and data.clan.name in h2 tag

Comment: I would create another component that takes the data as it's props, and renders each bit of data itself. <h1>{data.clan.name}</h1> etc. Example would be: {loading ? "Loading...." : <Clan data={data}>}

Comment: hey can you please edit your answer to showcase this part making new component and passing props to it and using it on elements including loading while fetching too

Comment: Done. But id also recommend you watch/read a tutorial on functional react instead of being spoon fed, good luck.

Comment: @SuperiorJacob generally it is best to provide a code answer with proper  explanation. This is not considered sppon feeding.